# How to align one line of text without adding extra space between lines?

Tags: html, css

For example, I want the following format

```
             Nov/1 2013
This is a sunny day

            Nov/12 2013
A friend visits my home

                    ...
```

The date line is `right` aligned, while the content line is `left` aligned.

I tried `<div>`, it added extra space between the two lines.

Comment: you want Nov/1 2013 This is a sunny day in one line?

Comment: can you provide the code (css & html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wFhqP/1/)**

Is that what you're looking for?

**HTML**

```
<p class="paragraph">
    <span class="right-aligned">Nov 13</span>
    This is a sunny day
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.paragraph {
    display: inline-block;
}

.right-aligned {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It is optional to define a width for the paragraph in this solution.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/3YyPa/

this

```
<div id="box">
    <p class="text-right">Nov/1 2013</p>
    <p class="text-left">This is a sunny day</p>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

and

```
#box{
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.text-left{
  float: left;
}
.text-right{
  float: right;
}
p{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

should do the trick!

Comment: you can also use css-atribute text-align if you don't want to use float.

Comment: Just to note using `left` and `right` as class names is unsemantic and bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/RaLwc/1/

```
  <div class="cont">
<span class="right">Nov/1 2013</span>
<span class="left">This is a sunny day</span>
<span class="right">Nov/12 2013</span>
<span class="left">A friend visits my home</span>
</div>




.cont
{
width:145px;
height:auto;
float:left;
}
.cont span
{
width:100%;
height:auto;
float:left;
}
.right{
text-align:right;
}
.left{
text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div align="right">Nov/1 2013<br/>
This is a sunny day
</div>
```

Produces:

Nov/1 2013
This is a sunny day

Comment: The HTML attribute `align` is deprecated. Don't use it.

Comment: True - this is better: <div style="text-align: right;">Nov/1 2013<br/> .. etc ... Not sure I've exactly answered the question though.

Comment: @usefulcat The question already states he uses `text-align: right` on the upper string anyway too.